# Deleted old email address from account logins, now two accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts, email-addresses

I decided to delete my old login email from my Stack Exchange account, hoping that the system would then only recognize my new email for login.

However, my associated account profiles and reputation are gone (except TeX where my reputation is set to 1). When I login on Stack Overflow however, I can still see my reputation on the other subsites.

(removed, can only post two links with this low reputation)

How can I finally make that email change without losing all the reputation associated with my old email address?

As I see now, I am also only a user+random number, not my usual nickname anymore, while my usual account still exists (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1829329/zelphir) and should be associated with this post.

Also I still see my old email address in my Stack Exchange account, although that was the one I deleted.

Instead, now the two other email logins, which were in there before I deleted the old login disappeared! Exactly the opposite of what I wanted.

## Update

When trying to fill the form for merging accounts on the contact page, I get the following issue:

> oops! this isn't a link to a valid profile

for *both* accounts.

Comment: Have you tried linking to specific profiles rather than the network account? Other than that I'm not sure... If you can't get it to work just choose the "Other" reason and include the links in the body, explaining what happened.

Comment: @Cai is correct, you can't merge network profile since they are not actual accounts. You can do that only per-site.

Comment: You ignore what we say and remove the proof that you just don't know how to  use the merge form? Nice.

Comment: @ShadowWizard AdamLear suggested OP remove the screenshot since it included multiple personal email addresses

Comment: @Cai but since it's not relevant anyway, better just remove this whole "Update" section. If anyone new to this question will now read it, he/she can wonder "why it failed?" and try asking OP to clarify, explain, etc, and it's just waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @ShadowWizard After contacting the Stack Overflow Team they merged my two accounts. As I clearly stated in my OP the merge form did not work. Now it may be that I had to enter something else than the URLs to my profile in that form, but if so there was no indication for that, which I saw. Since it simply didn't work that way, I don't know what is up with your attitude? Also I don't know how you come to the conclusion, that I wouldn't clarify something if asked?
Did you comment under the wrong post maybe?
Maybe you can add some _constructive_ criticism instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, one is not supposed to use a google address with the normal email login function, but has to use the google option for that instead. When I added the gmail address as a google login address everything worked as expected and I can now login with my gmail address. This is also the only thing I did differently from the first time, when I added the gmail address to the "other" logins, regarding the addition and removal of email addresses to my account.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you removed the credential from your main account successfully, and then ended up logging in with it on stackexchange.com, which created a new account... or something went a bit sideways on stackexchange.com itself. Hard to say off-hand.

Either way, the easiest way to fix this would be to contact the team via the "contact us" link, choose "other" from the topic dropdown and request network-wide deletion of this new account along with your Stack Exchange OpenID credential that you no longer wish to use. Feel free to reference this thread for context.

You should then log out of this account (click Stack Exchange in the top left, then log out). Log back in with your desired Gmail credential, and you should be all set as far as accessing your account goes (and the requested deletion will clean up what you no longer want to use).

As a side note, you still use your old email address as the contact email on most site profiles under your main account. The fastest way to change that, if you wish, would be to edit your profile and save it to all communities.

And as a side side note, you might not want to keep the screenshot with your email address(es) shown publicly in your question here. :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: To edit my profile and save to all sites is what I've tried actually, which resulted in the current situation : (
Also surprising is, that I cannot login on SE with my new credentials, only with the old ones, into the new account, but not with the new credentials into the old account. I currently don't know how I can login to my old account on SE.
About the screenshot: Yes you are probably right : )

Comment: @user113985 logging in with the old credentials is exactly what caused the problem so don't do that (I understand this question is attached to that account now, but apart from that). If you can't log in to your old account using the new credentials then you need to go through the account recovery and get a new password, and use the same contact form if you have trouble.

Answer (score 1):

As for what exactly happened, I'm not sure. But, it seems you somehow accidentally created a second account in the process. At a guess you probably removed the email, then accidentally logged back in with that email which created another account. You can see you have two separate profiles ([Zelphir](https://stackexchange.com/users/2050137/zelphir) and [user113985](https://stackexchange.com/users/9176498/user113985)).

Use the [contact form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and explain what happened (include a link to both profiles) and a member of staff will help you merge the accounts.

Comment: There is a problem with merging the two accounts as well, I'll add information to my question.